problem with NavigationStack inside NavigationLink inside NavigationSplitView
in a new SwiftUI mac app project, paste below code
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            NavigationLink {
                NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                    VStack {
                        Button("Show 1") {
                            path = [1]
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { selection in
                        Text("You selected \(selection)")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("sidebar object")
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("detail")
        }
    }
}

run the project, then click the "sidebar object" button in sidebar, then click the "Show 1", would somehow show a yellow warning mark:

However, after asking some AI and twisting its code, I make it works just by surround Text("detail") with another NavigationStack, see below code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            NavigationLink {
                NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                    VStack {
                        Button("Show 1") {
                            path = [1]
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { selection in
                        Text("You selected \(selection)")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("sidebar object")
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                Text("detail")
            }
        }
    }
}

Can someone tell me what happen here? Is this the right way of doing things?
p.s. I used to use UIKit, and just trying to learn SwiftUI not long ago

Can you describe what kind of UI you are trying to build? This way of using NavigationSplitView is not documented - it "just so happens" to work here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Sweeper Ultimately, I want to have a list on side bar, clicking item from the list show detail view on NavigationSplitView, clicking a button on the detail view can go to a "deeper" detail view on NavigationStack.

Currently the only documented way to navigate to the detail view of a NavigationSplitView is through a List selection (see the examples in the documentation). A destination-based NavigationLink like in your code is not officially supported.
Since you wanted the sidebar to be a list anyway, this works out greatly.
@State private var path = [Int]()
@State private var selection: Int?

var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            // you can use value-based NavigationLinks here
            // e.g. here I have added a NavigationLink with 'value: 0'
            // so when this is selected, 'selection' will be set to 0
            NavigationLink("sidebar object", value: 0)
            // add more list rows with ForEach, perhaps...
        }
    } detail: {
        if let selection {
            // you can use 'selection' here in this view
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                VStack {
                    Button("Show 1") {
                        path = [1]
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { selection in
                    Text("You selected \(selection)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            // this is the view that will be shown when nothing is selected
            Text("Please select something in the sidebar!")
        }
    }
}


I have played with NavigationSplitView & NavigationLink more myself.
In your answer, the NavigationLink only make the list item selectable, and the "value: 0" doesn't seem to do anything.
Provided I have declare a list variable, the same list be done withList(list, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { Text("option \($0)") }, which doesn't need NavigationLink.
The only case I found using NavigationLink inside NavigationShplitView reasonable is the list having a .navigationDestination modifier. What do you think?
Anyway, I accept the answer and thanks for answering.

By the way, I found the official doc of NavigationLink having this problem too, replace NavigationLink(color.description, value: color) with Text(color.description) seems to just fine.

@JayTang the value parameter just determines what value the list selection binding should be set to, when the navigation link is selected. It is kind of pointless if you also use tag or ForEach, but it is what it is. And yes, it doesn’t have to be NavigationLink, but NavigationLink has a unique appearance on iOS, with a chevron on the trailing edge. Screen readers might also treat them differently.

Second Code Fix:
•   The second code adds a NavigationStack around the Text("detail") in the detail section.
•   This ensures that the detail section is managed by a NavigationStack, providing the necessary context for navigation and state management.
•   By adding the NavigationStack in the detail section, the navigation state (path) is properly maintained and observed, allowing the navigation to work as expected.
Key Difference:
•   The key difference is that the detail section in the second code is wrapped in a NavigationStack, ensuring that the navigation context is properly handled. This provides a consistent and predictable behavior for navigation, as the NavigationStack manages the path and destinations.
Hoping that I helped you!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
